# add a new line in svg, bug cannot see the line

Tags: jquery, svg

I want to add a new line into the svg
when, the add button is pressed, a new line should be added into the svg
I can sure the line is added in the elements, but why it is not displayed on the screen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#map
{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
line
{
    stroke:rgb(0,0,0);
    stroke-width:3;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){
        var newLine=$('<line id="line2" x1="0" y1="0" x2="300" y2="300" />');
        $("#map").append(newLine);
    });
})
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h2 id="status">
0, 0
</h2>
<svg id="map" width="800" height="600" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line id="line" x1="50" y1="0" x2="200" y2="300"/>
</svg>
<button id="add">add</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In order to add elements to an SVG object those elements have to be created in the SVG namespace.  As jQuery doesn't allow you to do this at present (AFAIK) you can't use jQuery to create the element.  This will work:

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
    newLine.setAttribute('id','line2');
    newLine.setAttribute('x1','0');
    newLine.setAttribute('y1','0');
    newLine.setAttribute('x2','300');
    newLine.setAttribute('y2','300');
    $("#map").append(newLine);
});
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/ePz5h/).

Comment: From MDN: you (apparently) should use [DOM2 methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course#Scripting_in_namespaced_XML) such as `setAttributeNS()`

Answer (score 12):

with little bit less code

```
 $("#add").click(function(){
      $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line')).attr({
          id:"line2",
          x1:0,
          y1:0,
          x2:300,
          y2:300
      }).appendTo("#map");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by reading the svg elements innerHTML property
and then writing it back to the svg elements innerHTML property
This forces an element refresh.