# How to create SVGPathElement from SVGSVGElement

Tags: javascript, svg, path, element

i want to create SVG in JavaScript. I have SVG element (JS type SVGSVGElement), this type have methods as createSvgRect, createSvgTransfrom, ... but haven´t createSvgPath. How i can in SVG create a path?

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg.setAttribute("width", (200).toString());
svg.setAttribute("height", (200).toString());
// there i need to create path from svg object
```

Comment: Please show your code!

Comment: Check discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547117/add-a-new-line-in-svg-bug-cannot-see-the-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<path>` is an element so you just call createElementNS to get one e.g.

```
var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
```

You seem confused about createSVGRect. That doesn't create a `<rect>` element, it creates a rectangle object which is used to model things like the viewBox attribute.

Comment: Can we specify the *path points* throw the code instead of setting the attribute "d"?