# Can't animate 2 objects at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, svg, line

So I finally managed to get my object moving and rotating properly.

Now I want to move and rotate 2 lines at the same time. However when a new line is created the earlier lines stop working. The objects remain, values etc are still correct although the movement and rotations don't work anymore.

When retrieving info about the lineObject I get unique ones back for both of them.
The move and rotate functions both are being called and looped through correctly.

The set attribute seems to be broken for earlier ones when a new one is created.

What is going wrong here?

`this.lineObject.setAttribute(parameters);` doesn't seem to do anything.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQrXPo

Comment: Don't you want it with css3 transformation and animation?

Comment: @Salasar I'm quite "noob" with css, html etc. I didn't see an "easy" way to do this since the object is constantly moving as well so the variables have to be based on the location of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with how you create your line tags in the Draw function.
When you use innerHTML, that essentially recreates the entire contents of container. That means that when you draw the second line, your first gets orphaned, and a new element is created in its stead.

Instead you should use appendChild. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Also, when you create the line element take a look at [add a new line in svg, bug cannot see the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547117/add-a-new-line-in-svg-bug-cannot-see-the-line) 
Otherwise your lines will be invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Low-level animation in js is very uncomfortable and requires many lines of code, if you don't use any libs.
Maybe CSS3 can help you? See this [tutorial](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/).

I was write example for you case. See at [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/SlevBsxCtWvIKq7MTBco/)

Comment: You should really put the answer in the question. The plnkr should be an optional extra.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was helpfull. But because bug-a-lot explained why it happened he got accepted.