# SVG - Adding a line with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I wrote a simple code to add a line into my svg page when I click a button

This is the html

```
<body>
<svg  width="500" height="400">
</svg>
<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
</body>
```

And the Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
      $("svg").append(' <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="40" y2="40" style="stroke: black">' );
    console.log("done!");
  });
});
```

And jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dch7xyez/1/

The line gets appended but its not visible. Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: it gets appended you just cant see it, so maybe the styling is wrong ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy I know it appends the question is why It's not visible? I put the exact string on html and It worked! But when I use the javascript it won't show up

Comment: What UA are you running this on. IE won't fix up the namespaces so your content will end up in the HTML namespace instead of the SVG namespace.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm on firefox

Comment: @omidh "the question is why It's not visible? " - no the question was why doesnt it work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try doing it this way : https://jsfiddle.net/dch7xyez/2/

```
var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
newLine.setAttribute('id','line2');
newLine.setAttribute('x1','0');
newLine.setAttribute('y1','0');
newLine.setAttribute('x2','200');
newLine.setAttribute('y2','200');
newLine.setAttribute("stroke", "black")
$("svg").append(newLine);
```

[add a new line in svg, bug cannot see the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547117/add-a-new-line-in-svg-bug-cannot-see-the-line)

Comment: And when you're also creating a dynamical SVG-element itself, you need to use the namespace too: `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')`. And it would probably be a good idea to set `display: block;`, and `svgElem.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')`.